# How automatically rename a file with its date ? (backup php)

Tags: php, ftp

This code create db backup file, but the file name have always the same name so I need to manually rename them. How would you write a code to automatically insert the date and hours of this backup in their title? (eg: backupDB-07.08.12-18h43) or something like that?

My code:

```
<?
echo "backup of your database

";
$db="nom_de_ma_base";
$status=system("mysqldump --host=mysql5-1.perso --user=$_POST[login] --password=$_POST[password] $db > ../$db.sql");
echo $status;
echo "Compression du fichier.....

";
system("bzip2 -f /homez/backupDB/$db" . date("d-M-Y", time()) . ".sql");
echo "C'est fini. You can access to your database
\n
";
?>
```

Comment: You seem to know how to do it, by concatenating the date in the rest of the string... You can do the same in the `mysqldump` line as well.

Comment: Also in shell there is `date`, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the date thing in the wrong place.  Put the timestamp into a string variable and add that one to where the backup sql file is actually written.

The idea of putting it in a variable is that it might change between the start of the write operation, and the start of the compression operation.

```
<?
echo "backup of your database

";
$db="nom_de_ma_base";
$datestamp = date("d-M-Y", time());
$status=system("mysqldump --host=mysql5-1.perso --user=$_POST[login] --password=$_POST[password] $db > ../$db" . $datestamp .".sql");
echo $status;
echo "Compression du fichier.....

";
system("bzip2 -f /homez/backupDB/$db" . $datestamp . ".sql");
echo "C'est fini. You can access to your database
\n
";
?>
```

Comment: Glad I could help out Giom.  May I ask you to pick one of the answers you got and accept it?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply include a variable containing the date after `$db.sql` ? 
Something like this code:

```
<?
echo "backup of your database";
$db="nom_de_ma_base";

$date = date('d.m.Y', time());
$filename = $db.'-'.$date;
$status=system("mysqldump --host=mysql5-1.perso --user=$_POST[login] --password=$_POST[password] $db > ../$filename.sql");
echo $status;

echo "Compression du fichier.....";
system("bzip2 -f /homez/backupDB/$filename.sql");
echo "C'est fini. You can access to your database\n";
?>
```

As you can see I've added a variable named `$filename`.
It contains `$db` and `$date` so in the end you have `my_database_name-08.07.2012`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got 4 replies in 2 mn, you are great tftd!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$curdate = date('Y-m-d_g-i-s');
echo "backup of your database @".$curdate."\n\r";
$db="nom_de_ma_base".$curdate;
$status=system("mysqldump --host=mysql5-1.perso --user=$_POST[login] --password=$_POST[password] $db > ../$db.sql");
echo $status;
echo "Compression du fichier.....

";
system("bzip2 -f /homez/backupDB/$db.sql");
echo "C'est fini. You can access to your database
\n
";
?>
```

Comment: Hi waqar! Your code is perfect ! I also tried it! It works super! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$Command='tar -cvf All-backup_'.date("Y-m-d").'.tar Backup_ftp-'.date("Y-m-d").'.tar Backup_sql_'.date("Y-m-d").'.sql.gz';
if(exec($Command))
echo 'backup done !';
```

Comment: Atmon you are great! I fund for the hour on your code (was missing on the one above) thanks a lot!!! Have a great day!